# How to deliver a UX/UI project from adobe xd to the client?

Tags: export, interface-design, client-relations, adobe-xd, presentation

How do you guys deliver the projects to your clients?

Do you export the screens you made as PNG files and compact it?
Do you send the raw file (.xd or .sketch, etc.)?
Or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could ask your clients about their preferences.

Comment: This is a broad question for the main site, not suitable for the Q&A format (there won't be just one correct answer) maybe you could ask on [meta]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. Unfortunately, I see several problems with your question: 1) It is a survey, not a request for general information (which is what we do). 2) It appears to be more about UX than graphic design, but it’s hard to tell without further details. 3) Your situation is not very specific. — If you can, please [edit] your question to address this or ask on [ux.se]. For example you could describe your situation in more details and ask something along the lines of: “I would deliver in form of …, but I have doubt about this, namely … Is this a problem and how can I solve this?”

Comment: @Luciano: I fail to see how this would be on-topic on Meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I always try to meet with the client in person, so I can explain my design choices and show the design directly in person.**

If that is not possible then I will make a prototype in Invision or Marvel and send a link to the client. I make sure that the settings are correct so my prototype looks good on different screen sizes (no horizontal scroll bars etc.).

Sometimes besides my Prototype I make a small project file, where I show my choices, colors, typography, pictures etc. There are a lot of examples on sites like Behance.

It is really important that the clients understands the story and your choices, so try to explain this as good as possible. Don't be afraid to be creative when presenting your work!